# Alternative parsing methods

Tags: parsing

I know something about regular expressions, parse trees and abstract syntax trees. But once I read there is still another parsing technique that, as far as I remember, people from SO used to re-implement its markdown parser.

What I don't recall is the name of this method, or how it did work. Do you? If not, what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of [Parsing Expression Grammars](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~baford/packrat/)?

(If I'm remembering the same thing you're remembering, it's [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) writing about this [here](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/01/markdown-and-introduction-to-parsing.html).)

Comment: As cletus wrote in his article about markdown I confused it with markdownsharp, about which I read about the same day (last january to be more precise).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog about SO's markdown parser: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/

Here's the source:  http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

It does use advanced regular expressions.  I'm not aware of any "other" technique of parsing.  The most common solutions for parsing used by virtually all programmers are:

- Regular expressions (or finite state machines) for regular grammars.
- Non-deterministic pushdown automata for context-free grammars.  This is where you get parser generators like yacc, bison, ANTLR, etc.

See also the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) of formal grammars.